# How to determine brushless DC (BLDC) winding pattern, based on poles and slots?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I am trying to figure out how to determine the correct winding pattern for a 3-phase BLDC motor, given that there are 10 poles and 18 slots. I have seen the very interesting post [here.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/355710/finding-number-of-pole-pairs-in-a-bldc-motor), but as the 10-pole 18-slot pattern has not been confirmed, I am wondering how these patterns were devised in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

An updated version of that chart can be found at [www.bavaria-direct.co.za](http://www.bavaria-direct.co.za/info/). Here it is:-

[image]

Based on the legend `Colors (by Relph Okon)` I am guessing they *have* been confirmed. It was probably compiled from the results of experimental winds done by several people.

However many combinations can be calculated by multiplying the patterns of those with fewer poles (eg. 4 poles and 6 teeth has the same pattern as 2 poles and 3 teeth), or applying some basic rules.

The essential rules are that the number of poles must be even and the number of teeth must be divisible by 3. Secondary rule is they must not be equal (eg. 6P-6T) or an exact multiple of same (6P-12T). Best combinations seem to be where they are as close to the same as possible within those rules (eg. 2P-3T, 10P-12T, 14P-15T).

Comment: But what is affected by different pattern? For instance, 16-poles motor, what's the difference between 15 and 18 slots? Or 24, as i would guess.

Comment: (You could take it from [the man (Dr. Ralph Okon) himself](http://powerditto.de/Kombinationstabelle.html).)