# Need help grasping the routing of coils for stator and rotor

Tags: motor, winding

I can see it with just a 3 coil motor, whether it be in different configurations, but loads of different motors have some 72 or umpteen different stator slots and winding for the rotor.

It was my original understanding, whether true or false, that per each configuration whether it be an A/C configuration or delta the three coils repeat around the stator and rotor.

So for a stator with 72 slots there would be 24 sets of coils starter, north, and south.... All in succession. However when looking at some of the industrial motors online I'm having a hard time making out how exactly I'd route the windings if I were trying to sketch up a 120 slot motor as apposed to a 72 slot motor, and quite frankly I'm not sure I'd be able to replicate or rewind one if I were to simply reproduce it.

The litz wire all seems to blend together when I try to trace the windings through either the rotor or stator.

- If I were trying to design a motor, power output and what not aside, how exactly would I wind one?
- What would the routing look like for rotor and stator with say 3, 6,
  9, or 12 sets of coils?
- Does this configuration simply repeat for a stator with 72 stator slots?

Comment: You can't realistically do this without also knowing the magnetic configuration of the rotor. Then there are standard configurations : saw a good analysis of this a few months ago, will try to find it again

Comment: here. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/483177/how-to-determine-brush-less-dc-bldc-winding-pattern-based-on-poles-and-slots?rq=1 It doesn't go as high as 72 poles but you may be able to use it (e.g. 18 slots * 4) if your rotor matches one of the rotor pole counts  (* 4).

Comment: For 3-phase AC motors, the three phases can be connected in either a wye (star) or delta stator configuration. I don't know what an "A/C configuration" might be. Litz wire is seldom if ever used for motor windings. Only DC commutator motors, universal motors and wound-rotor induction motors have rotor windings. In 3-phase stators, a winding pattern is repeated for each pole and each phase within each pole. You should first determine the type of motor. Learn motor terminology. Many steps and calculations are required to design a motor. Determining the winding configuration is not the first step

Comment: To answer a question like this, it would help to know what you know about motors and what your objective is. As stated, the question seems to indicate that you are trying to learn about the design of motor winding configurations without learning about the design objectives and constraints that determine the choice of winding design. Even if the question is stated clearly, it may still be too broad to answer in this forum. It likely requires many pages and diagrams.

Comment: I'm really not trying to design a motor, not yet at least, I'm just trying to describe my confusion I guess... When I look at diagrams for a configuration they look like an old stater from a 70's motorcycle, there's 6 poles or 2 sets of 3 phases and they're clearly situated and wound around a single pole at a single position.... I'm just not seeing a definitive pole with motors that have umpteen slots.... They all overlap and whilst I'm sure I'm wrong it looks like the magnetic field between say phase 1 and 2 might interfere with each other...  How does one discern between each phase?

Comment: The phase windings often overlap. The magnetic fields don't interfere with each other, they are summed together. During the course of one half cycle of the power waveform, the strongest part of the magnetic field shifts from the windings of one phase to the next to the third. That is what causes the stator field to rotate.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too broad and is developing into a discussion rather than a single specific question.