# Where to find winding diagram for a 56 pole 63 slot BLDC motor?

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, algorithm, construction

I'm working on an algorithm to control a BLDC motor with 56 poles and 63 slots. I'm using trapezoidal control. By employing usual switching sequence (CA - CB - AB - AC - BC BA) I'm missing one step in the six step commutation. Where am I going wrong?

I found above switching sequence is referenced to the standard winding sequence(ABCABC). There are winding sequence table available for upto 20 pole BLDC. If I get the correct winding sequence, I can edit my algorithm to make positive torque without missing any steps.

- Can anyone provide the winding sequence information for 56 pole 63 slot bldc?
- Is there any standard text books I can refer regarding the practical BLDC motor construction?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From these two answers you can get some of the background info...

[How to determine brushless DC (BLDC) winding pattern, based on poles and slots?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/483177/how-to-determine-brushless-dc-bldc-winding-pattern-based-on-poles-and-slots?rq=1)

[Finding number of pole pairs in a BLDC motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/355710/finding-number-of-pole-pairs-in-a-bldc-motor?rq=1)

Neither of them covers your precise use case. However, as 63/9 = 7 and 56/8 = 7, I would suggest you take the 9 slot(tooth) 8 pole winding from those diagrams [(source : "Home built electric motors")](http://www.bavaria-direct.co.za/info/) as a starting point and replicate it 7 times round the circumference.